# Doing some maths to calculate range using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I am trying to create a range display using Javascript. It is not a range slider as such, but will display the range of 2 values within a div.

[image]

I'll try to explain with an example:

- The outer 'style-range' div holds the absolute min and max values and is exactly 183px wide. This is the boundary of the range display.
- The inner 'range' div also has min and max values that need to be highlighted like in the screenshot. So for this example, it will be a very small width highlighted area close to the left edge of the range display.
- The inner span needs to be the darker pointer within the range.

  ```
  <div class="col-sm style-range abv" data-step="0" data-max="15" data-min="2" data-name="abv">
      <div class="range" data-min="2.2" data-max="3.3">
          <span data-value="2.7"></span>
  </div>
  ```

This is literally as far as I got with the javascript...

```
// calc the range of an attribute
recipe.calcRange = function() {

    var $item   = $( '.ranges [data-name="abv"]' );

    var width   = $item.width();
    var diff    = $item.data( 'max' ) - $( item ).data( 'min' );

}
```

I need help with the Javascript portion of this to do the math calculations. I would basically need to convert the values of 2.2 and 3.3 into their relevant % positions within the range slider.

So 2.2 might become 5%, meaning that it starts 5% from the left boundary and 3.3 might be 16%, meaning that it ends at 16% from the left boundary.

Comment: And the question is....?

Comment: @SamAxe edited to actually ask a question

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/qr7yp2nx/

Comment: maximum divided by value = percent.   `183 / 2.2` and `183 / 3.3`

Comment: @ChrisG - yep that's exactly the idea. The maths seems off though. If I set the span value to either 2.2 or to 3.3, the line does not go to the ends of the range

Comment: Yes, I just fixed it I think. Load the URL again please

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thanks heaps